# error 500 al intentar crear una cuenta con ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, nodejs

tengo un problema al intentar registrarme me lanza un error 500 en la consola de google.

en el log errores no me aparece nada sobre el error quizas el problema es al momento de cargar la libreria jquery pero no logro saber exactamente que hacer.

soy muy nuevo en todo esto muchas gracias.

```
 public function actionSignup()
{
    $user = new Users();
    $model = new SignupForm(['scenario' => 'signup']);
    $siteSettings = Sitesettings::find()->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])->one();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        /*$phone_no = explode('+', $model->phone);
        $phone = $phone_no[1];
        $usermobileCheck = Users::find()->where(['phone' => $phone])->one();
        if (!empty($usermobileCheck)) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash("success", Yii::t('app', 'PhoneNumber already exist'));
            return $this->render('signup', ['model' => $model]);
        }*/
        $model->userstatus = 1;
        if ($siteSettings['signup_active'] == 'no') {
            $model->activationStatus = 1;
        } else {
            $model->activationStatus = 0;
        }
        if ($user = $model->signup()) {
            if ($siteSettings['signup_active'] == 'yes') {
                $mailer = Yii::$app->mailer->setTransport([
                    'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                    'host' => $siteSettings['smtpHost'],
                    'username' => $siteSettings['smtpEmail'],
                    'password' => $siteSettings['smtpPassword'],
                    'port' => $siteSettings['smtpPort'],
                    'encryption' => 'tls',
                ]);
                $user = new Users();
                $emailTo = $_POST['SignupForm']['email'];
                $verifyLink = Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl('/verify/' . base64_encode($emailTo));
                try {
                    if ($user->verifyEmail($_POST['SignupForm']['email'], $verifyLink, $_POST['SignupForm']['name'])) {
                        Yii::$app->session->setFlash("success", Yii::t('app', 'Please verify your acccount using given email id'));
                        return $this->redirect(['site/login']);
                    }
                } catch (\Swift_TransportException $exception) {
                    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', Yii::t('app', 'Sorry, Verify mail not send, SMTP Connection error check email setting'));
                    return $this->redirect(['site/login']);
                }
            } else {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash("success", Yii::t('app', 'Your account has been created, Please Login'));
                return $this->redirect(['site/login']);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hola juan, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta, elimina las imágenes, y agrega tu código y mensajes de error como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos y lograrás que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, gracias. 
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!.

Comment: Los errores 500 son errores de servidor (código PHP en este caso), nada tienen que ver con jQuery o Javascript. Te aconsejo que aprendas a revisar el log de errores del servidor. Si por el momento no sabes dónde se encuentra ese archivo, puedes poner estas tres líneas al inicio de tu código en php: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` así, deberás ver en pantalla o en consola cuál es el motivo exacto del error.

Answer (score 0):

tal y como dices el codigo escrito no tiene error de sintaxys, por lo que el error debe estar, o bien en otra parte de tu codigo, o es un problema de servidor, te dejo la explicacion de lo que significa cada numero de codigo de error que hay en tu consola:

1. El error 401 significa "No autorizado" y se produce cuando el
   cliente intenta acceder a un recurso que requiere autenticación,
   pero no proporciona las credenciales adecuadas. Por ejemplo, si
   intentas acceder a una página que requiere inicio de sesión, pero no
   has iniciado sesión o has proporcionado credenciales incorrectas,
   podrías recibir un error 401.
2. El error 404 significa "No encontrado" y se produce cuando el
   cliente intenta acceder a un recurso que no existe en el servidor.
   Por ejemplo, si intentas acceder a una página que ha sido eliminada
   o movida a una nueva ubicación, podrías recibir un error 404.
3. El error 500 significa "Error interno del servidor" y se produce
   cuando el servidor encuentra un problema que le impide procesar la
   solicitud del cliente. Este error puede tener muchas causas, como
   problemas de programación, fallas de hardware o software, o
   sobrecarga del servidor. Cuando se produce un error 500,
   generalmente se muestra un mensaje de error genérico al usuario, ya
   que la causa exacta del error puede no estar clara.

Dato no menor, tu pregunta no corresponde a las buenas practicas dentro de stack overflow, pone el codigo en la descripcion de tu pregunta, no como comentario. corres el riesgo de que cierren la pregunta.